# avoid using any in the expressjs + typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a method in node/express/typescript, like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
export const errorConverter = (err: any, req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  let error = err
  if (!(error instanceof ApiError)) {
    const statusCode =
      error.statusCode || error instanceof mongoose.Error ? httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST : httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    const message = error.message || httpStatus[statusCode]
    error = new ApiError(statusCode, message as string, true, err.stack)
  }
  next(error)
}
```

and using it like this `app.use(errorConverter)`.

How can I avoid using `any` in the argument, what type can i use there. Need some help.

Comment: you could use `unknown`

Comment: @about14sheep, if i give err: Unknown, getting issues in error.statusCode

Answer (score 0):

Install the types required for express

```
npm i -D @types/express
```

Now import the interfaces for express

```js
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express"
```

and assign like this:

```js
const errorConverter = (
    req: express.Request,
    res: express.Response,
    nxt:express.NextFunction) => {
        // your logic here
})
```

or

```js
const errorConverter = (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    nxt: NextFunction) => {
        // your logic here
})
```

Comment: thanks sir, any idea how to add type for err.